# How is Laugwitz's work on Cauchy viewed by historians?

Tags: mathematics

Detlef Laugwitz is mainly known for his by-now-standard biography of Riemann:

- Detlef Laugwitz, [Bernhard Riemann 1826-1866 : Turning Points in the Conception of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=7U6njBdp_yoC&pg=PA219) (1996 - German ed.1996)

as noted in [this answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/what-were-riemanns-other-two-submissions-for-his-habilitation/2625#2625). He has written on Cauchy, as for example this text:

Laugwitz, Detlef. Infinitely small quantities in Cauchy's textbooks. Historia Math. 14 (1987), no. 3, 258–274.

How is Laugwitz's work on Cauchy viewed by historians today and why? I am interested in the *historians*' own position on the matter (rather than the opinions of SE editors).

Comment: Didn't you answer it here? http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2885

Comment: Just read the reviews of the book by historians.

Comment: @Conifold, I have my own position on the matter. I was wondering what the *historians* themselves think of it.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, that's a reply that can be given to *any* question on SE.

Comment: @katz: not exactly so: sometimes it is not clear where to search.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, there is a vast literature out there on Cauchy.  I can send you some of my own articles with a bibliography with over 100 items (you will have to take my word for it that they are all relevant :-) Not all of them have commented on Laugwitz.

Comment: @katz: I beieve you. Laugwitz's book is on my reading list. But not the 100 items you mention about Cauchy:-) The life is short, and history is only a hobby for me, not the principal occupation.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, Laugwitz only wrote a book about Riemann, not about Cauchy.